# Автоматические переходы между слайдами после всех анимаций в PowerPoint

Tags: powerpoint

Появилась необходимость автоматического перехода между слайдами по окончании всех анимаций на этом складе. Вариант с установкой времени не прокатит. Думаю, что простыми действиями такого эффекта не добиться, но может быть можно это реализовать макросами? Но и тут проблема: о них только слышал и больше ничего.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить данную проблему?

Comment: `Вариант с установкой времени не прокатит` - это почему это? У каждой анимации есть время воспроизведения, если она не зациклена, конечно, в чем тогда проблема сложить время каждой анимации и скипать слайд по прошествии этого времени? Каждому слайду можно установить свое время, через которое он скипается, так что считаешь для каждого отдельного слайда время анимации и устанавливаешь скип для каждого слайда отдельно.

Comment: @Pekor, потому что переход нужен только после последней анимации, которая проигрывается по щелчку, так что привязка ко времени здесь не подойдет.